# ::before with the same content as the first child

Tags: css

I am creating various css buttons that looks like this:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh ;
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: column ;
  justify-content: center ;
  align-items: center ;
}

.btn {
  position: relative ;
  padding: 10px 20px ;
  overflow: hidden ;
  margin: 2px ;
  display: flex ;
  align-items: center ;
  background-color: transparent ;
  color: #912BFF ;
  text-decoration: none ;
  font-size: 15px ;
  border-radius: 4px ;
  border: 2px solid #912BFF ;
}

.btn::before {
  content: 'Hello 1' ;
  position: absolute ;
  top: 0 ;
  left: 0 ;
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  display: flex ;
  justify-content: center ;
  align-items: center ;
  background-color: #912BFF ;
  color: #fff ;
  transition: all 0.5s ease ;
  opacity: 0 ;
  transform: scale(2) ;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1) ;
  opacity: 1 ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Hello 1</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Hello 2</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Hello 3</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Hello 4</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Hello 5</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Hello 6</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Hello 6</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Hello 7</a>
</body>
```

Now instead of having 'Hello 1' as the contents, I want to have the content match for the other classes as well. So when the content is 'Hello 2' for the link, the ::before pseudo element will also have the 'Hello 2' content so that it could work with any buttons created dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's important to be satisfactory.
It is easily editable because you only need to change one attribute and you don't have to write the same in two places.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh ;
  display: flex ;
  flex-direction: column ;
  justify-content: center ;
  align-items: center ;
}
[data-content] {
  position: relative ;
  padding: 10px 20px ;
  overflow: hidden ;
  margin: 2px ;
  display: flex ;
  align-items: center ;
  background-color: transparent ;
  color: #912BFF ;
  text-decoration: none ;
  font-size: 15px ;
  border-radius: 4px ;
  border: 2px solid #912BFF ;
}

[data-content]:after {
content: attr(data-content) ;
}

[data-content]:before {
  content: attr(data-content) ;
  position: absolute ;
  top: 0 ;
  left: 0 ;
  width: 100% ;
  height: 100% ;
  display: flex ;
  justify-content: center ;
  align-items: center ;
  background-color: #912BFF ;
  color: #fff ;
  transition: all 0.5s ease ;
  opacity: 0 ;
  transform: scale(2) ;
}

[data-content]:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1) ;
  opacity: 1 ;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" data-content="Hello 1"></a>
  <a href="#" data-content="Hello 2"></a>
  <a href="#" data-content="Hello 3"></a>
  <a href="#" data-content="Hello 4"></a>
  <a href="#" data-content="Hello 5"></a>
  <a href="#" data-content="Hello 6"></a>
  <a href="#" data-content="Hello 7"></a>
  <a href="#" data-content="Hello 8"></a>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Css:

```
.btn::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}
```

Html:

```
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-text ="Hello1">Hello 1</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-text ="Hello2">Hello 2</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-text ="Hello3">Hello 3</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-text ="Hello4">Hello 4</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-text ="Hello5">Hello 5</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-text ="Hello6">Hello 6</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-text ="Hello7">Hello 7</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn" data-text ="Hello8">Hello 8</a>
```

If I understand you correctly, that's what you want. it will now dynamically change according to the data-text attribute you gave.

Comment: Instead of simplifying the code, you now have to write the same thing twice. This is not dynamic, only manually specified for each element